# "Invalid use of aggregating function in this context" in a SET query (Neo4j)

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, aggregates

I wonder why this is considered an invalid use of aggregate functions in Neo4j's Cypher:

```
MATCH (p:Project)-[:EMPLOYS]-(n:Person) SET p.youngest = MIN(n.age);
```

While the following is considered a valid use case:

```
MATCH (p:Project)-[:EMPLOYS]-(n:Person) RETURN p.name, MIN(n.age) AS youngest;
```

How should I rewrite the first query to make it valid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for "why" your original Cypher attempt does not work, and the answer by @mah does work: Cypher only permits aggregation functions to be used in `WITH` and `RETURN` clauses.

Comment: why? What's the purpose of this implementation?

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck You can ask the neo4j folks that, say on one of their [Slack channels](http://neo4j.com/blog/public-neo4j-users-slack-group/).

Answer (score 9):

A slight change to the query makes it work:

```
MATCH (p:Project)-[:EMPLOYS]-(n:Person)
WITH p, MIN(n.age) AS min_age 
SET p.youngest = min_age;
```

Comment: I fixed a slight typo in this answer, and reformatted the Cypher a bit.