# Aggregating to set values for a relationship in Neo4j v2.3.3

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to use existing data to create a new relationship type.  I'm trying the strategy [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491698/invalid-use-of-aggregating-function-in-this-context-in-a-set-query-neo4j) but I'm not getting the expected results.

This:

```
MATCH (user)-[r:POSTS_TO]->(thread)<-[s:POSTS_TO]-(other) 
MERGE (user)-[act:TALKS_TO]->(other)
```

works, creating unique relationships between users who have posted in the same forum threads, but there are no relationship properties set for `TALKS_TO`.  I'd like to add the number of threads each user share to the relationship, with the aim to delete the underlying `POSTS_TO` relationships.

When I try this:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[r:POSTS_TO]->(thread:Thread)<-[s:POSTS_TO]-(other:User) 
WITH thread, count(r.thread_id) as total_threads
MERGE (user)-[act:TALKS_TO]->(other)
ON CREATE SET act.total_threads = thread.total_threads
```

only two nodes (neither of which are user nodes) and one relationship are set, and no properties.

I have also tried

```
MATCH (user:User)-[r:POSTS_TO]->(thread:Thread)<-[s:POSTS_TO]-(other:User) 
WITH thread, count(thread) as total_threads
MERGE (user)-[act:TALKS_TO]->(other)
ON CREATE SET act.total_threads = thread.total_threads
```

with the same results.

I can't see where I am going wrong in comparison [with this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491698/invalid-use-of-aggregating-function-in-this-context-in-a-set-query-neo4j).  Critiques & corrections please?

This is the full set of data that I'd like to set as a property for each `TALKS_T0` relationship:

```
MATCH (user)-[r:POSTS_TO]->(thread)<-[s:POSTS_TO]-(other) 
WITH r, 
    min(r.event_time) as first_post, 
    max(r.event_time) as last_post, 
    count(distinct r.post_id) as total_posts, 
    count(distinct r.thread_id) as total_threads,
    count(distinct r.forum_id) as total_forums
MERGE (user)-[act:TALKS_TO]->(other)
ON CREATE SET act.first_post = first_post,
          act.last_post = last_post,
          act.total_posts = total_posts,
          act.total_threads = total_threads,
          act.total_forums = total_forums
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working correctly:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[r:POSTS_TO]->(thread:Thread)<-[s:POSTS_TO]-(other:User) 
WITH 
user, 
other, 
thread, 
r.first_post as first_posts,
r.last_post as last_posts,
r.total_posts as total_posts_to_thread
WITH 
user, 
other,
sum(total_posts_to_thread) as total_posts,
count(thread) as total_threads, 
min(first_posts) as first_post, 
max(last_posts) as last_post
MERGE (user)-[act:TALKS_TO]->(other)
ON CREATE SET act.first_post = first_post,
          act.last_post = last_post,
          act.total_posts = total_posts,
          act.total_threads = total_threads
```

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues with the first query you tried:

1. You did not include `user` and `other` in the `WITH` clause, so the `MERGE` clause did not see them, and was forced to create new nodes instead.
2. Your `SET` clause was using the value of `thread.total_threads` (which does not exist) instead of `total_threads`. Thus, the `SET` clause never created any properties.

This query fixes both problems:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[r:POSTS_TO]->(thread:Thread)<-[s:POSTS_TO]-(other:User)
WITH user, other, thread, count(r.thread_id) as total_threads
MERGE (user)-[act:TALKS_TO]->(other)
ON CREATE SET act.total_threads = total_threads;
```

*COMMENT 1: The `POSTS_TO` relationship has a redundant `thread_id` property, since the relationship's `Thread` end node presumably has the same `id` value.
COMMENT 2: If you get rid of the `POSTS_TO` relationships, then it looks like the `Thread` nodes will end up totally disconnected. You may need to think more carefully about what you are trying to accomplish.*

Comment: Thanks for your help!  The purpose of this is to try and remove the `Thread` nodes and `POSTS_TO` relationships entirely and use the aggregated information to set properties about the `TALKS_TO` relationships, so that is what I would expect.  I've tried the solution you suggested and it does set relationships for each person-to-person interaction, but now I'm finding that `total_threads` is always 1, which I would not expect.  I'll keep tinkering.

Comment: Update: after a lot of pondering, poking around and trying different things, I changed the structure of the data to include a `total_posts_count` as a property of the `POSTS_TO` relationship. Then when I created the `TALKS_TO` relationship, I could sum the `total_posts_count` to get a sense of relationship strength between each pair of users. I still can't figure out why the number of threads appears to be distinct, as in reality pairs of users may communicate together in multiple threads, but the important thing was to get the `TALKS_TO` relationship to supercede `POSTS_TO`.